# What do the assumptions for 2SLS (two-stage least squares) mean in the context of instrumental variables?

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables, 2sls, identifiability

The assumptions for 2SLS are (z are the vector for instrumental variables; x are the explanatory variables in the model; u are the vector for the error term):

Assumption 2SLS.1: E(z'u)=0,

Assumption 2SLS.2a: rank(z'x) = k

Assumption 2SLS.2b: rank(z'z) = m

m is the number of available instrumental variables; k is the number of endogenous variables (I think it means the x vector here).

I think Assumption 2SLS.1 implies that z and u are uncorrelated. But what do Assumption 2SLS.2a/b mean?

Comment: please also define $m$ and $k$

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure that the position of $k$ and $m$ is not the wrong way round?`

Comment: It is on the slide I got.

Comment: Then please ask your instructor, or compare with the entry in Wooldridge's book from which that likely is taken - in the meantime, I posted an answer already.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you mind on which page was the entry? I have a Wooldridge's book (5th edition) with me but for some reason I cannot find it any more.

Comment: Page 99 in this one https://www.amazon.de/Econometric-Analysis-Cross-Section-Panel/dp/0262232588

Comment: I see it is a complete different book...

Comment: @ChristophHanck Sorry, I really made a mistake about the m and k. I hope that does not influence your answers. (Assumption 2SLS.2a is "rank(z'**x**) = k")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paraphrase Wooldridge's textbook:

2b requires the instruments to be linearly independent in the population. It is similar to the condition ruling out multicollinearity, which is typically easy to ensure unless instruments are chosen which are a linear combination of the others IVs.

Part a is the crucial rank condition for identification. It means that $z$ is sufficiently linearly related to $x$ so that rank $E(z'x)$ has full column rank.

Necessary for the rank condition is the order condition, $m\geq k$. That is, we
must have at least as many instruments as explanatory variables to achieve identification via 2SLS.

However, we further need the elements of $z$ to be appropriately correlated with the elements of $x$.

Comment: Sorry, I really made a mistake about the m and k. I hope that does not influence your answers. (Assumption 2SLS.2a is "rank(z'x) = k")

Comment: No, I already took that into account, so that the answer should stand.

Comment: Regarding part b: the left hand side does not contain x or x'. So how can a conclusion regarding x and z be drawn from it? Also am I correct that Assumption 2SLS.1 implies that z and u are uncorrelated?

Comment: The left-hand side of what? If you mean the lhs of the regression equation, it does not contain the instruments, right. But you can regress the regressors on the instruments to see if there is enough (partial) correlation. 2nd question: yes

Comment: Sorry. I was talking about the lhs of Assumption 2SLS.2b, i.e "rank(z'z)".

Comment: You are right, I referred to a and b the wrong way round. Edited.

Comment: Thank you. Just to make sure: Am I correct that "IV" in your answer mean "instrumental variable"? (Sometimes people use it for independent variable)

Comment: Yes, IV=instrumental variable here.